# Python function to sum integer values based on string values in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

The following is a subset of the data that I have:

```
VALID_CAR_NAMES = ['Audi', 'Holden', 'Honda', 'Mitsubishi', 'Toyota', 'Volvo']

car_data = {
    '1': {'Name': 'Emily', 'CarName': 'Toyota', 'Price': '1000'},
    '2': {'Name': 'John', 'CarName': 'Audi', 'Price': '30000'},
    '3': {'Name': 'Ben', 'CarName': 'Audi', 'Price': '35000'},
    '4': {'Name': 'Jasmine', 'CarName': 'Holden', 'Price': '17000'},
    '5': {'Name': 'Tara', 'CarName': 'Mitsubishi', 'Price': '1000'},
    '6': {'Name': 'Kristy', 'CarName': 'Mitsubishi', 'Price': '1500'},
    '7': {'Name': 'Eddy', 'CarName': 'Honda', 'Price': '2000'},
    '8': {'Name': 'Brett', 'CarName': 'Honda', 'Price': '2500'}
}
```

Here I'm trying to find the sum of the price column for each car in the list VALID_CAR_NAMES. And if there is no data for a car in VALID_CAR_NAMES, the sum will be None.

The output should look like this (e.g. here the sum for Volvo is None because there's no data for it in the input dictionary car_data):

```
{
    'Audi': {'sum': 65000}, 
    'Holden': {'sum': 17000}, 
    'Honda': {'sum': 4500}, 
    'Mitsubishi': {'sum': 2500}, 
    'Toyota': {'sum': 1000}, 
    'Volvo': {'sum': None}
}
```

So here's a function that I've tried to write. If I get rid of the else statement, it will sum up the prices for each car. But when I run the code with the else statement (to change the 0 into None for cars with missing/no data), I end up getting "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'int'". This leads me to think my approach is wrong...

```
def sum_car_price(car_data):
    sum_car_price_dict = {'Toyota': {'sum': 0}, 'Audi': {'sum': 0}, 'Holden': {'sum': 0},\
                      'Mitsubishi': {'sum': 0}, 'Honda': {'sum': 0}, 'Volvo': {'sum': 0}}
    for car_id, customer_data in car_data.items():
        for car_name, car_price in sum_car_price_dict.items():
            if customer_data['CarName'] in car_name:
                car_price['sum'] += int(customer_data['Price'])
            else:
                car_price['sum'] = None
    return sum_car_price_dict
```

Comment: change "car_price['sum'] to 0 after else statement instead of None

Comment: `def sum_car_price(x):`
    `global car_data ` use this

Comment: Hi @RishabhSemwal, Apologies, I think I wasn't very clear. I wrote car_price['sum'] = None after the else statement because I wanted to change the sum of car prices that had missing data to None instead of 0. For example, Volvo has missing data in the input dictionary car_data so I want to change that to None...

Comment: One thing I want to know whats should be put inside sum_car_price argument when it is called

Comment: so that it gives you the desired output

Comment: Because argument of sum_car_price cannot be a dictionary. It may be a car name

Comment: remove car_data from inside sum_car_price() function first. Use car_name instead of its place and then use car_data as a global variable inside function

Comment: So the argument for the function "sum_car_price" is "car_data" which is the dictionary I pasted at the very top of my question.

Comment: Yeah exactly.   car_data is used as a dictionary inside the function so it cannot be a argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this?

```
def sum_car_price(car_data):
        result = {}
        for car in VALID_CAR_NAMES:
            data = [int(c["Price"]) for c in car_data.values() if c["CarName"]==car]
            result[car] = {"sum":sum(data ) if data else None}
        return result
```

Comment: Hi @Robin, thank you very much for your reply. When I tried running it in IDLE, I seem to be getting an error for this line car_data = [int(c["Price"]) for c in car_data.values() if c["CarName"]==car]. AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: In your question, car_Data is a dictionary so it should work. How you pass the argument to the sum_car_price function?

Comment: Hi @Robin, I wish I could send a photo to show you what I'm doing. But at the top of the code I've got the VALID_CAR_NAMES list, and below that I've got the car_data input dictionary. Then below car_data I've got the code you've written. To test the code you wrote, I've added a print statement at the bottom- print(sum_car_price(car_data)). And for some reason I seem to be getting an AttributeError as described in the first comment I wrote

Comment: Sorry, @Tabata I just updated the code. Use the current version.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta love lambdas, generators and list comprehensions:

```
prices = lambda c: (int(cd["Price"]) for cd in car_data.values() if cd["CarName"] == c)
x = {c: {"sum": sum(prices(c)) or None} for c in VALID_CAR_NAMES}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_car_price(car_data):
    """This function takes a dictionary of clean data (car_data) and
    finds the sum total price for each car in the list VALID_CAR_NAMES.
    The return value is a dict with the sum price for each car"""

    sum_car_price_dict = {'Toyota': {'sum': None}, 'Audi': {'sum': None}, 'Holden': {'sum': None}, 'Mitsubishi': {'sum': None}, 'Honda': {'sum': None}, 'Volvo': {'sum': None}}

    for car_id, customer_data in car_data.items():
        if customer_data['CarName'] in VALID_CAR_NAMES:
            if sum_car_price_dict[customer_data['CarName']]['sum'] == None:
                sum_car_price_dict[customer_data['CarName']]['sum'] = customer_data['Price']
            else:
                sum_car_price_dict[customer_data['CarName']]['sum'] += customer_data['Price']

    return sum_car_price_dict
```

You could just pre-initialize the dictionary with None values beforehand, and then simply check if it is already None, and act accordingly.

Comment: Hi @edusanketdk, thank you for your reply. When I tried running it in IDLE, I got a "KeyError: 'carName'", so I think the if statement should be customer_data['CarName'] instead. After changing that, I got another error for the second if statement (if sum_car_price_dict[car_id]['sum'] == None:). This time I got KeyError: '1'

Comment: Hey, I have edited the code since you tried it. Check it now, it works fine :)

Comment: Hi @edusanketdk, thank you for editing the code and now the sum of Volvo is None!. I'm sorry to be a pain, but now the output of the code isn't summing up the prices. For example, the sum for Audi is 35000 instead of 65000. The sum for Mitsubishi is 1500 instead of 2500. And the sum of Honda is 2500 instead of 4500.

Comment: Oh sorry for the trouble. In the else condition I forgot to write += instead of = . Check it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_car_price(car_data):
    """
    This function takes a dictionary of clean data (car_data) and 
    finds the sum total price for each car in the list VALID_CAR_NAMES.
    The return value is a dict with the sum price for each car
    """

    # initialize all valid cars' count to 0
    sum_car_price_dict = dict( (key, {'sum': 0}) for key in VALID_CAR_NAMES)

    # iterate through all the data
    for car_id, customer_data in car_data.items():
        car_name = customer_data['CarName'] 
        if car_name in VALID_CAR_NAMES:
            try:
                sum_car_price_dict[car_name]['sum'] += int(customer_data['Price'])
            except KeyError:
                pass

    for value in sum_car_price_dict.values():
        if value['sum'] == 0:
            value['sum'] = None

    return sum_car_price_dict
```

The problem is, you should not directly add an `int` to `None` in mid-way.

Comment: Also you can dump the second `for` loop to make the code more efficient. And if neccessary, use a `try-except` block to handle the key-not-found-error.

Comment: Hi @Moenupa Wang, thank you for your reply! I tried running it in IDLE, and I seem to be getting 'Volvo': {'sum': 0} instead of None

Comment: @Tabata just have it fixed by adding a loop to sweep the `0`s to `None`s

Answer (score 0):

Considering your requirement, this should work. Main reason for the error is your order of nesting the for loops.

```
for car_name, car_price in sum_car_price_dict.items():
    for car_id, customer_data in car_data.items():
        if customer_data['CarName'] == car_name:
            car_price['sum'] += int(customer_data['Price'])
    if (car_price['sum'] == 0):
        car_price['sum'] = None
```